# Output fdisk bash command to multiline variable

Tags: bash, command, fdisk, output

I can't seem to figure out how I can put a fdisk command from a bash script in a multiline variable.

Here is my code

```
hdds="$(sudo fdisk -l | grep "Disk /dev/sd" | awk '{print$2}' | sed 's/://g')"
```

When I execute this bash script it puts everything on a single line like

```
/dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

When I execute this command outside of the bash script it works like it should

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep "Disk /dev/sd" | awk '{print$2}' | sed 's/://g' | wc -l
```

Where the output is `2`.

I have tried putting everything in quotes, without quotes and what not but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you calling the variable with `echo`, by any chance?

If so, put it in double quotes, like this:

```
echo "$hdds"
```

or use `printf`:

```
printf "%s" "$hdds"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. So if I understand, the variable contains 2 lines but echo without quotes makes it a one liner?

Comment: I believe this answer will give you precise answet to why, where and when quotes would work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/357628